# How can I correct typos faster in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, spell-checking

I love the spell check in intellij, but it's so annoying to use. To fix a typo, you have to right click, hover over "spelling" click "Typo: change to", and then select an alternative from a new list that pops up. I just want to right click and click the word I want, or hover, or have a keyboard shortcut. There's gotta be a better way.

Comment: Hey Conor, I noticed you haven't mark my answer as the accepted one, is there a reason for that? Or you just forgot? If not, please elaborate on why.
Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, accepting answers help future readers, even though there is just one answer, it appears as accepted in the results and encourage users to check. It also encourages people to answer questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without using mouse, you can simply press `ALT + Enter` (`option + Enter` on Mac) when on your variable, then select what you want and enter.

It's quite fast, and typos should be an exception.

Comment: Also use a shortcut for `Main menu | Navigate | Next/Previous Highlighted Error`.